# Parallel MAC vs doubled rounds for SipHash, KMAC and others

Tags: mac, siphash, kmac

SipHash 4-8 is documented by the authors as being about half the speed of SipHash 2-4 and is obviously the more conservative option.

I was wondering from a security perspective how this would compare with performing SipHash 2-4 with two different keys and XOR-ing the outputs? Albeit one would need 2 128-bit keys (as opposed to 1 128 bit key for 4-8), but one could then perform the individual hashes in parallel.

My intuition would be that even if there were an attack that breaks SipHash 2-4, the doubled key length would require that the attack reduce the security by at least half in order for this parallel construction to be less secure than SipHash 4-8.

Would this generalize as well to other MACs that use "rounds" of some form (e.g. KMAC could be represented in this way, HMAC not really)?